# jQuery get css properties based on regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I'm trying to build some custom js for an app, and I've got to a point where I need to replicate some css styles from a parent item.

```
...
match_properties: ['background-color', 'border-radius', 'margin'],
...

var custom_css = [];
$(params['match_properties']).each(function(i, v) {
    custom_css.push(v+': '+$(params['object']).css(v));
});
custom_css = custom_css.join('; ');

css_properties = css_properties + custom_css + ';';
```

Is there anyway from jQuery to get all the `'border-radius'` properties from an item (`'moz-border-radius'`, `'webkit....'`)?

The point is, not to do something like the following, by hand

```
if(params['match_properties']['border-radius']) {
    custom_css.push('-moz-border-radius: '+$(params['object'].css('-moz-border-radius')))
    custom_css.push('-webkit-border-radius: '+$(params['object'].css('-webkit-border-radius')))
}
```

and the reason not to do so, because it would be much more efficient to just pass the `'border-radius'`, `'box-shadow'`, or what ever and get all the properties related

Comment: it's `$.each(ary, fn);`

Comment: @user1737909 I'm sorry, but what are you referring to, because I don't get it?

Comment: `$(params['match_properties'])`

Comment: @user1737909 you propose to use it this way: `$.each($(params['match_properties']), function(i, v){})` ? Why?

Comment: I propose it this way : `$.each(params['match_properties'], function(){});`

Comment: still, why? For being shorter, and kinda cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
var custom_css = [];
$.each($(params['match_properties']), function(i, v) {
    custom_css.push(selectr($(params['object']), v));
});
custom_css = custom_css.join('; ');


function selectr(element, selector) {
    var selectors = {
        browser: ['border-radius', 'box-shadow'],
        shorthand: ['margin', 'border'],
    }

    var my_css = [];

    if($.inArray(selector, selectors.browser) > -1)
    {
        my_css.push('-webkit-'+selector+': '+$(element).css('-webkit-'+selector));
        my_css.push('-moz-'+selector+': '+$(element).css('-moz-'+selector));
        my_css.push(selector+': '+$(element).css(selector));
    }
    else if($.inArray(selector, selectors.shorthand) > -1)
    {
        my_css.push(selector+': ' + 
            $(element).css(selector+'-top') + ' ' +
            $(element).css(selector+'-right') + ' ' +
            $(element).css(selector+'-bottom') + ' ' +
            $(element).css(selector+'-left')
        );
    }
    else
    {
        my_css.push(selector+': '+$(element).css(selector));
    }

    return my_css;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.9 and later:

```
var props = $('whatever').css(['background-color', 'width', 'font-size']);
```

That returns an object with properties corresponding to the CSS properties you asked for.

Comment: including `'-moz-...'`, `'-webkit-...'` if I pass something like `'box-shadow'` ?

Comment: @w0rldart no, I don't think it'll do that; jQuery doesn't make any attempt to keep track of those things. If you explicitly ask for them, however, I suspect it'd work.

Comment: @w0rldart you could always write a little filter function that'd take an array of property names and apply prefix expansions for things like "box-shadow" and "transition".

Comment: ok, I understand... in that case, your answer only helps me improve my code, by writing less, and thank you for that

Comment: yea, that's what I'm trying now